# Restarting Phone when it is shutdown

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way to start the phone automatically after every 'n' minutes after shutdown... I am developing a solution for this but not getting any success. Any help or link to the solution will be highly recommended. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not turn the device on from an app on the device, for the obvious reasons. There is however a way to boot the device from the computer.
If the device had `usb debugging` turned on, you can use `adb` and run `adb reboot` to boot the device connected by usb to the computer.